# Field calculator (using ATAN)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, spatial-analyst

How do I input the arc tan in the field calculator given the values of the fields to get the desired answer, I compare the answer of the manually computed arc tan value and the Atan Spatial Analyst tools. the answer that I get from the Atan Spatial Analyst tool is different from the answer that I computed manually. so I want to calculate the arc tan values using the field calculator but how do I input it in the expression box?

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to clarify the version of ArcGIS for Desktop that you are using, please?  Also, you mention the Field Calculator but is it that or the Raster Calculator that you are using?  The more precise you can make the details, the more likely your question is to attract potential answerers.

Answer (score 5):

Check "Python" in the field calculator.  `math.atan()` will be useful for you but don't forget this: the result of `math.atan(10.0/12) = **Result**` is in *radians*. You have to convert it to degrees or (whatever unit of measure you want to use).

How you can convert:

```
(**Result** / PI) * 180 = 42
```

Comment: +1: the caution about degrees *versus* radians is perceptive and the use of a worked example makes the point particularly clear.  Nice first answer!